# AngularJS $http.get executing PHP to delete file. IE still finds file after deleting?

Tags: php, angularjs, http, browser-cache

**This is on Internet Explorer only.**

I have a factory that provides notifications for my app.
The input for those notifications is a file (qc.sta) that is created automatically by a third party software and is dropped in a specific folder.

Whenever that file exists, a new notification is added to the app.
My mechanism would be to get the data from that qc.sta file and then delete it after collecting the data.

To delete a file I need to execute a PHP that deletes the file, but this seems to have to be done inside a $http.get, so I end up with an $http.get inside another $http.get.

What happens is that the notifications (triggered on a $interval inside the controller) keep popping up continuously, despite the file being deleted.

**My factory is as below:**

```
myApp.factory("qcSTA", function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        apiPath: "data/qc.sta?rnd=" + new Date().getTime(), //randomizing request to prevent caching
        getNotifications: function () {
            //Creating a deferred object
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            //Calling Web API to fetch notifications
            $http.get(this.apiPath, { headers: { 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'} })
            .success(function (response) {
                //Passing data to deferred's resolve function on successful completion
                //Does whatever needs to be done to the response before passing it on
                function deleteFile() {
                    $http.get("deleteFile.php");
                    return false
                };
                deleteFile();
            deferred.resolve(JSON.parse('{"item" : "' + response.itemNumber + '", "description" : "' + response.desc + '"}'));
            })
            .error(function () {
                //Sending a friendly error message in case of failure
                deferred.reject("An error occured while fetching items");
            });
            //Returning the promise object
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
});
```

**And my controller:**

```
myApp.controller("notificationController", function ($scope, $location, $interval, $q, qcSTA) {
    function getNotifications() {
        qcSTA.getNotifications()
        .then(function (data) {
            $scope.notifications.push(data);
        },
        function (errorMessage) {
            $scope.error = errorMessage
        });
    }
}
```

How can I ensure the notification only pops up once rather than going in circles?
Could this be cache related?
If I refresh the browser, it won't get more notifications, it's like it finally detects the qc.sta file isn't there anymore.

Comment: Having new date().getTime(), and no-cache headers appended to the deleteFile.php  does not affect the outcome. u_u')

Comment: Do you ever remove this notification from array? Show how the array gets used. Don't create json manually...it is error prone and there is no need to use it when you can simply use an object

Comment: I'll have to look at using JSON automatically. I did try it before, but wasn't accepting in the controller, hence I came up with rebuilding it manually and passing the manual string reconverted into an object. I haven't done the code to remove notifications from the array yet.

Comment: so wouldn't it need to be removed from array? Suspect the logic in your interval needs to be examined. Some of the code above is not using best practices either

Comment: I just tried to remove items from the array. By popping them, the ng-repeat updates automatically, which is brilliant. I'm aware the code isn't using best practices, I'm still a newbie in javascript.

Comment: really want to `splice()` the array so you remove the proper ones